# Spring Integration org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-integration

I keep getting the below exception in my Spring Integration project:

```
HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:9502/clients/clientId] in the [bean 'retrieveClientIdConfigurationFlow.http:outbound-gateway#0' for component 'retrieveClientIdConfigurationFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/abs/integration/services/RetrieveClientIDConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method retrieveClientIdConfigurationFlow']; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for com.abs.retrieveclientid.request.TransactionType and content type "application/x-java-serialized-object"here
```

My bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
fun retrieveClientIdConfigurationFlow(
    xmlRequestTransformer: XmlRequestTransformer,
    xmlResponseTransformer: XmlResponseTransformer,
    responseTransformer: ResponseTransformer
): IntegrationFlow =
    IntegrationFlows
        .from(INPUT_CHANNEL)
        .transform(xmlRequestTransformer)
        .handle(
            Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9502/clients/clientId")
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .expectedResponseType(String::class.java)
        )
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(ClientId::class.java))
        .transform(responseTransformer)
        .transform(xmlResponseTransformer)
        .channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
        .get()
```

I receive request XML file, after which I make call to retrieve clientId which should be used to generate response XML.

It seems that clientId is not even created when executing hanlde method ( no increase in DB). When trying endpoint in postman, id is generated and content type is "application/json".

I have tried message converters, but none of them worked. Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> No HttpMessageConverter for com.abs.retrieveclientid.request.TransactionType and content type "application/x-java-serialized-object"

The request even doesn't reach your server. That exception is thrown from here in the `RestTemplate.doWithRequest()`:

```
String message = "No HttpMessageConverter for " + requestBodyClass.getName();
if (requestContentType != null) {
    message += " and content type \"" + requestContentType + "\"";
}
throw new RestClientException(message);
```

You need to be sure what to do with that `com.abs.retrieveclientid.request.TransactionType` in the request payload.  Perhaps you need to transform it more exactly into just a `clientId`, or convert it into a `Map` for form data in the request body. May even convert it into a JSON...

We just don't know what is your service contract. Please, clarify editing your question.